# How to Get Article and Comment Without Id In Url Using Php

Tags: php

I have a php code like this to get Posting with comment using php MVC, but I have to using url to get url ID and select posting and comment with the url id:

url id: `http://localhost/blogs/my-article-title/12`

the code in my controller like this:

```
public function index($title, $id)`
    {
        $post = $this->load->model('Posts')->getPostWithComments($id);
}
```

And in my Models like this:

```
public function getPostWithComments($id)
    {
        $post = $this->select('p.*', 'c.name AS `category`', 'u.first_name', 'u.last_name', 'u.image AS userImage')
                     ->from('posts p')
                     ->join('LEFT JOIN categories c ON p.category_id=c.id')
                     ->join('LEFT JOIN users u ON p.user_id=u.id')
                     ->where('p.id=? AND p.status=?', $id, 'enabled')
                     ->fetch();

        if (! $post) return 

        $post->comments = $this->select('c.*', 'u.first_name', 'u.last_name', 'u.image AS userImage')
                               ->from('comments c')
                               ->join('LEFT JOIN users u ON c.user_id=u.id')
                               ->where('c.post_id=?', $id)
                               ->fetchAll();

        return $post;
    }
```

The above code is used when I want to see posts and comments on the article pages, but I am confused, how to get a post with comments without having to use the id of the existing url, I mean when I want to open the home page of the website, the posts and comments Directly in the show.

I'm trying to do this on my controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $post = $this->load->model('Posts')->getPostWithComments();
    }
```

and this in my models, but I just get all post and not for all comments and I have an errors in there:

My Models:

```
public function getPostWithComments()
    {
        $post = $this->select('p.*', 'c.name AS `category`', 'u.first_name', 'u.last_name', 'u.image AS userImage')
                     ->from('posts p')
                     ->join('LEFT JOIN categories c ON p.category_id=c.id')
                     ->join('LEFT JOIN users u ON p.user_id=u.id')
                     ->fetchAll();

        if (! $post) return null;

        $post->comments = $this->select('c.*', 'u.first_name', 'u.last_name', 'u.image AS userImage')
                                ->from('comments c')
                                ->join('LEFT JOIN users u ON c.user_id=u.id')
                                ->fetchAll();
        return $post;
    }
```

Can someone help me to show all posting and all coment in each posting in my php code without using url id?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to first get all the posts URL Ids from the database and then call your `getPostWithComments($id)` on each of the the url ids.
For example:

```
$urls = array(**an array containing urls gotten from DB**);
$posts = array(); //initialize an empty array so we can store the posts here
foreach($urls as $url) {
    $posts[] = load->model('Posts')->getPostWithComments($url);
}
```

now you can integrate through `$posts` and access each post.

Comment: I mean, what can I do to show posting with a comment in my homepage without url id. Normal like this `getPostWithComments($id)`, but I mean, how to get posting with comment but not using url id like this getPostWithComments(). thanks before for your respond.

Comment: url id is used when the request method is GET. If you want it not to be shown in url you can use request method POST, but i think this is not the right convention. Anyway, how in the first place you choose those specific post to be shown in the home page? Are you just showing the last post id in the table?

Comment: I think if you read my answer again, you will find I answered your question. First select all the IDs from the database, then pass them to `getPostWithComments($id)` and save the results in an array, then iterate through that array and display the data on your homepage.

Comment: to get all your post urls, you `SELECT id FROM posts WHERE status="enabled"`